# How to find duplicate elements' index in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

Is there any STL function in C++ that allows me to find all indices of duplicates in an array?

For eg:

```
int array[] = {1,1,2,3,4};
```

Should return 0,1

Comment: Made a cheeky edit; presumably you wanted an array of integers, not an array of pointer to integers and a truck load of UB?

Comment: I'm thinking you could do this with `std::sort`, `std::adjacent_find` and a loop.

Comment: Is it OK to change the array? Is it OK to change the array temporarily? Is it OK to create temporary arrays? See @NathanOlivier's comment if changes are OK.

Comment: @Bathsheba, Yes, your edit was right. I meant an array, not array of pointers.

Comment: @NathanOliver But any solution with sorting would lose the original indices.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Can you please elaborate? I'm new to STL and I don't quite get you.

Comment: @juanchopanza That it would.  I missed that part.

Comment: The type in the array are always *integer* (or build-in type anyway)? This could influence the design choice of the algorithm

Comment: @Raghav is your input data already sorted (as your demo data suggests)?

Comment: @BiagioFesta Yes, they're all integers.

Comment: There is not a single function but you could certainly use algorithms to solve this. Is the data sorted?

Comment: @m.s. No they're not sorted.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? Asking for indices is a bit of code smell - it is better to work with collection at higher level. So it is likely there is a higher-level solution to the eventual goal, just not to this step.

Comment: If the range of integers content is something small (like up to 0..1000000 elements), and the array is large, you can do variation on count-sort, which will be O(n) then.

Comment: @JanHudec, The aim is to get all indices and use them in a different array as its index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Efficiently, you could use a `std::unordered_set`(to uniquely keep track of duplicate indices) and `std::unordered_map`(to keep track of unique numbers and their indices).

This does it in `O(N * [O(1) + ... + O(1)])` *...approximately =* `O(N)`:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator>
std::vector<int> get_duplicate_indices(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last){
    std::unordered_set<int> rtn;
    std::unordered_map<int, int> dup;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; first != last; ++i, ++first){
        auto iter_pair = dup.insert(std::make_pair(*first, i));
        if(!iter_pair.second){
            rtn.insert(iter_pair.first->second);
            rtn.insert(i);
        }
    }
    return {rtn.begin(), rtn.end()};
}
```

Explanation:

Given an array `A`

- Using a set of unique indices, `rtn`.
- Using a `KV` (Key-Value) map, `dup`; where `k` is an element in the array `A`, and `v` is the index of that element in the array.
- For Each item, `a` with index `i` in the array:

  - find `kv` if `a` exists as `k` in `dup`
  - If it exists,

    - Insert `i` into `rtn`
    - Insert `v` into `rtn`
  - Else, add `a` and `i` as `kv` into `dup`
- return `rtn`

See a full example: <kbd>[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7023303d0ddbe5da)</kbd>.

---

For an input of:

```
int array[] = {1,1,2,3,4};
```

We have an output of:

```
1 0
```

Again,

For an input of:

```
int array[] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 0, 9};
```

We have an output of:

```
7 0 5 1 6
```

If you need the indices in order, you could simply sort the resulting array.

Comment: To have the indices in order, you can also use a `set` instead of a `unordered_set` and you won't need to sort the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an out of the box STL way of doing this. Here's an O(N*N) solution:

```
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 4};
    constexpr int size = 5; // ToDo - don't hardcode this.
    bool duplicates[size] = {};

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        if (!duplicates[i]){ /*No point in re-testing*/
            for (std::size_t j = i + 1; j < size; ++j){
                if (array[i] == array[j]){
                    duplicates[i] = duplicates[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

An approach based on sorting may prove more efficient for longer arrays: but you would have to build a table of new position -> old position to obtain the indices of the duplicate elements.

Comment: That shoots the complexity up to O(N^2). It cannot be done in less than that?

Comment: Hm, this is O(n**2), while sorting may be closer to O(nlogn).

Comment: @Raghav: I can't think of a "pivot"-style approach that would give you O(N log N).

Comment: well, it's generally accepted that quick sort is nlogn ... :) But that's just O() notation, if the OP is interested in real world performance, he should rather post true constraints of data and structures, because lean n**2 can be still quicker than dirty nlogn, for favourable n.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents on this. Not quite sure about the big-O of this one though (looks like O(N) to me):

```
std::vector<std::size_t> findDuplicateIndices(std::vector<int> const & v)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> indices;
    std::map<int, std::pair<int, std::size_t>> counts; // pair<amount, firstSeenPos>

    for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; ++i)
    {
        std::size_t const amount = ++counts[v[i]].first;
        /**/ if (amount == 1) // First encounter, record the position
        {
            counts[v[i]].second = i;
            continue;
        }
        else if (amount == 2) // Second encounter, add the first encountered position
            indices.push_back(counts[v[i]].second);

        indices.push_back(i);
    }
    return indices;
}
```

> [Try it online!](https://ideone.com/l0RMTb)